# How to check if a shortcode exists?

Tags: templates, shortcode

I'm using `do_shortcode` function to add shortcode in my template. But i would like to check if that shortcode exists before display them.

I mean like this

```
If (shortcode_gallery_exists) {
  echo do_shortcode('[gallery]');
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[#23572](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23572) introduced [shortcode_exists()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_exists/) into 3.6.

Answer (score 7):

I think you could use the following code to do this:

```
$content = get_the_content();
//write the begining of the shortcode
$shortcode = '[gallery';

$check = strpos($content,$shortcode);
if($check=== false) {
  //Code to execute if there isn't the shortcode
} else {
  //Code to execute if the shortcode is present
}
```

*(Caveat: not tested)*

Comment: This works, without the "[" in the shortcode name.

Answer (score 3):

Found this online somewhere and used is once or twice

```
//first we check for shortcode in the content
$tempContent = get_the_content();
$tempCheck = '[gallery';

$tempVerify = strpos($tempContent,$tempCheck);
if($tempVerify === false) {
  //Your Shortcode not found do nothing ? you choose
} else {
    echo do_shortcode('[gallery]');
}
```

.

*(i know the [gallery is missing the ].. leave it like so)*

**This should be used inside the loop**
..
Hope this helps, Sagive

Comment: OMG @Ryan beat me to it.. :) we posted a few seconds apart i guess cuz i didnt see hes answer :) apologies ryan - you came first..

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own function,

```
// check the current post for the existence of a short code
function has_shortcode( $shortcode = NULL ) {

    $post_to_check = get_post( get_the_ID() );

    // false because we have to search through the post content first
    $found = false;

    // if no short code was provided, return false
    if ( ! $shortcode ) {
        return $found;
    }
    // check the post content for the short code
    if ( stripos( $post_to_check->post_content, '[' . $shortcode) !== FALSE ) {
        // we have found the short code
        $found = TRUE;
    }

    // return our final results
    return $found;
}
```

The in your template write a conditional like,

```
if(has_shortcode('[gallery]')) {  
    // perform actions here  
}
```

Idea from this [NetTuts link](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-improving-shortcodes-with-the-has_shortcode-function/)

Comment: 3.6 is introducing [has_shortcode()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode)

Answer (score 1):

WP now has a built-in function for this:

```
<?php
 
if ( shortcode_exists( 'gallery' ) ): ?>

    // The short code exists.

<?php else: ?>

   // It DOESN'T EXIST

<?php endif;?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_exists/

Answer (score 0):

WordPress allows you to check whether a shortcode exists or not.

To check it you can use [`shortcode_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_exists/) function. It returns true if the shortcode exists.

```
<?php if ( shortcode_exists( $tag ) ) { } ?>
```

Where `$tag` is the name of shortcode you want to check.

```
<?php
if ( shortcode_exists( 'latest_post' ) ) {
    // The short code exists.
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old question but someone may still need this, especially because `shortcode_exists()` may not work for some plugin shortcodes:

```
$shortcode_result = do_shortcode('[your_shortcode]');

if ($shortcode_result != [your_shortcode]) && 
    !empty($shortcode_result))] {

    // do what you need

} else {
    // this is not valide shortcode
}
```